Construction time complexity of suffix automata
I was reading about suffix automata on cp-algorithms. I didn't completely understand their argument that redirecting transitions will take linear time in total. I only understood the first part, where as you go up the suffix link from $p$, the longest suffix of $s$ decreases in length. I was wondering if someone could explain the rest of the argument in simpler terms.

A better explanation can be found in the book chapter Automata for Matching Patterns by Crochemore and Hancart. The section on suffix automata starts at the bottom of page 26 (note that the PDF numbering is off by one, this is page 26 as printed on the paper, but page 27 of the PDF); pseudo-code for the algorithm is in two figures on page 33; and the complexity is explained in page 36 more precisely than the linked cp-algorithms article.
In that part of the algorithm, we are replacing transitions $(p,c,q)$ with $(p,c,\mathit{clone})$. Each state $p$ in this loop represents a set of suffixes of the string $s$ encoded so far. Look at the starting position of the longest suffix, in other words, $\mathit{index}_s(p) = |s| - \mathit{len}(p)$. As we go up the suffix-link chain, the length of the suffixes gets smaller, so the corresponding starting positions $\mathit{index}_s(p)$ are monotonically increasing. Furthermore, the final index of this inner loop is less than or equal to the starting index the next time we reach this inner loop. The rest of this answer explains this is more detail.
There is a subtlety that we shouldn't consider the first $p$ whose transition gets redirected to $\mathit{clone}$. Following the style of the book chapter I linked but using the notation of cp-algorithms, the pseudo-code looks like this, it should be a do-while loop (i.e., the loop body is entered unconditionally the first time):
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\texttt{do} & \\
&    \text{replace the transition }(p,c,q)\text{ with the transition }(p,c,\mathit{clone}) \\
&    p \leftarrow \mathit{link}(p) \\
\texttt{while} & (p \neq -1 \;\texttt{and}\;\text{there is a transition }(p,c,q))
\end{array}
$$
We consider the values of $p$ when we enter the $\texttt{while}$ condition (which thus ignores the initial value of $p$ before entering $\texttt{do}$).

During the loop, $\mathit{index}_s(p)$ (defined above) increases monotonically, because $\mathit{len}(\mathit{link}(p)) < \mathit{len}(p)$.
The value of $\mathit{index}_s(p)$ at the end of the loop is less than or equal to the value of $\mathit{index}_{s'}(p)$ the next time the loop runs (where $s'$ will be the "current string" when that happens).

The reason for the second point is that, at the end of the loop, if $p$ is defined (not $-1$), then its $c$ transition will not be pointing to $q$, but to $\mathit{link}(q)$, which is the same as $\mathit{link}(\mathit{clone})$ by construction of $\mathit{clone}$, and $\mathit{clone} = \mathit{link}(\mathit{cur})$. Thus, $\mathit{index}_s(p)$ will be equal to $\mathit{index}_{sc}(\mathit{link}(\mathit{link}(\mathit{cur})))$ (note the switch of indices from $s$ to $sc$). The next time the loop runs, the value of $p$ in the $\texttt{while}$ condition will necessarily have been obtained from following $\mathit{link}$ at least twice from $\mathit{latest}$ (once in a prior inner loop, and once in this do-while loop), which implies that its $\mathit{index}$ will be greater than the current $\mathit{index}_{sc}(\mathit{link}(\mathit{link}(\mathit{cur})))$.

Thanks for the lengthy reply. I've yet to read the article you linked, but I had some trouble understanding the last paragraph. I don't understand at the end of the loop, given that p is defined, why do you state that the 'c' transition get redirected to link(clone) instead of clone?
In the 2nd line of the do-while loop above, we replace transition (p, c, q) with transition (p, c, clone), not (p, c, link(clone)).

As long as there is a transition (p,c,q) we replace it with (p,c,clone). At the end of the loop, we will have found a state p with a transition (p,c,r) where r is different from q. That state won't be modified. The claim is that r must be equal to link(clone).

Ah, thanks for the explanation. I understand everything now.
